# URL Alias showing on checkout?

Tags: commerce

Drupal 7.38
Organic Groups
Drupal Commerce
Commerce Node Checkout

I have everything setup and working well.  There's one strange bug.  On checkout, I have Title displayed so the logged in user can create a new group, but URL alias also shows up.  I don't want this.  I have pathauto handling all this automatically.  Screen shot attached.  I've dug through all display settings.  I'm lost.  Any help would be appreciated.  Screen shot below.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission issue on the content type.